# Handling the real numbers, multiplication, and zero as a group

Tags: group-theory

A group can be formed using a set and a binary operator on elements of a set. Consider {$\mathbb{R}$, x}, the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and the multiplication operator x. There are nine product rules. Often letters are used for product rules, so think of p->+1, n->-1, and z-> 0:

- R1: p x p = p
- R2: n x n = p
- R3: p x n = n
- R4: n x p = n
- R5: z x z = z
- R6: z x p = z
- R7: z x n = z
- R8: p x z = z
- R9: n x z = z

The first four rules are the product rules for the cyclic group $Z_2$, or the sign group. By themselves, R1 and R5 are different representations of the trivial group $Z_1$. These 4 qualities are required to show that {$\mathbb{R}$, x} is a group:

- G1: Closure: $a$, $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $a x b$ is in $\mathbb{R}$
- G2: An identity $I$ exist for all in $\mathbb{R}$: $a I = I a = a$
- G3: An inverse exists for all in $\mathbb{R}$: $a a^{-1} = I$
- G4: The operation is associative: $(a x b) x c = a x (b x c)$

I will presume G1 and G4 (minimal requirements for a semigroup) and focus on G2 and G3.

For G2, the multiplicative identity is $1$, so this works for all elements in R, even zero since $0x1=1x0=0$.

It is well known that G3 does not work, that there is no $a^{-1}$ such that $0 x a^{-1} = 1$. To deal with this, it is common to consider the set $\mathbb{R}$\ $0$, the real numbers without zero as a group: {$\mathbb{R}$\ $0$, x}. This is in fact a group $Z_2$, using only rules R1-R4.

What is troubling is that $\mathbb{R}$ \ $0$ cannot have the rules R5-R9. With no z, the rules are undefined. Zero is not the same as undefined. Perhaps there have been mathematicians that have been upset by this observation that the set $\mathbb{R}$ \ $0$ makes product rules R5-R9 suspect.

Here is a possible resolution. Here is an an alternative to G2 where differences are denoted with stars:

*G2*: An identity *I(a)* exist for *every* in R *and Z1*: a I(a) = I(a) a = a

The addition of *and Z1* could be done to the original G2 without changing its meaning since $1x1=1$ by rule R1. The trivial group $Z_1$ and the addition operator has only one representation: $0+0=0$. The trivial group $Z_1$ and the multiplication operator has two representations: $1x1=1$ and $0x0=0$. The switch from all->*every* allows one to use a different representation of the trivial group to be the identity. This is why I->*I(a)*: the representation of the identity depends on the value of a. If and only if $a=z$, then the identity equals z, otherwise it is the far more familiar 1. The multiplicative inverse of z is z because $axa^{-1}=I(a)$ becomes: $0x0=0$. All 9 product rules will work for every real number, zero included.

Thus {$\mathbb{R}$ \ $0$, x} is a group, {$\mathbb{R}$, x} is not a group, but {$\mathbb{R}$, x} is a *group* based on the modifications to *G2* discussed above. Are there mathematicians who have argued along these lines?

Comment: I am really not sure what you are asking here. The interaction between addition and multiplication through the distributive law is important. If you are looking at multiplication only, you can have a multiplicity of algebraic structures, but the question is "what makes them useful?"

Comment: A different definition of the identity is being used. Instead of for all elements in R there is one and only one identity (1), I am saying for each element in R, there is one and only one identity, which can be either zero for zero, or 1 for everything else. To my eye, that is better because then {R, x} is a group, no need to remove zero.

Comment: You don't get a group if you have two different identities for multiplication - in a group the identity is unique.

Comment: I am using the trivial group $Z_1$ as the identity which happens to have two representations for multiplication, {0} or {1}. That is not a set {0, 1}. The uniqueness is at the level of the trivial group $Z_1$, not a particular representation of the trivial group $Z_1$, which would be {1}. The group $Z_2$ uses the first four product rules R1-R4 and is not central to the discussion. I noticed that {1} is both a real number and a way to represent the trivial group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to reuse the same name for a different algebraic structure. A group is a useful algebraic structure, and its definition is fine as it is.

However the algebraic structure you are talking about *has* been considered by some mathematicians, it just (for good reason) is not called a group. Instead it is called a [completely regular semigroup.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_regular_semigroup)

Comment: do mathematicians then say ${\mathbb{R}, x}$ is an example of a completely regular semigroup?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a mathematician who disliked the fact $(\mathbb R,\cdot)$ is not a group.  As far as I know, we are almost all content that it is a commutative monoid consisting of an abelian group with a zero element adjoined.

I know people think rings with local identities (that is, for each element, there is an element that acts like an identity for it), and I assume that people study semigroups with local identities too, which seems to be what you're angling at.

By the way, replacing "for all" with "for every" as you have does not really change the meaning that way (if that is what you intend.)  Rather, you have to change the order of the quantifiers:  "For each $a$ there exists an $I(a)$ such that..." .

Answer (score 0):

I agree you should not refer to this as a group. A group already has a well understood meaning, and trying to change the definition of a well accepted term will just cause confusion.

Depending on precisely what you mean (it is unclear what your modified G2 is stating), you may be noticing that $(\mathbb{R},\cdot)$ is an [inverse semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup). (EDIT: Or more strongly, a [Clifford semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_semigroup) which is a [completely regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_regular_semigroup) inverse semigroup.)

An inverse semigroup $(A,\cdot)$ is a semigroup where each element has a *unique* "inverse" in the following sense:
$$\text{For all } x \in A, \text{there exists a unique } y \in A \text{ such that } x = x\cdot y\cdot x \text{ and } y = y\cdot x\cdot y.$$

So when considering $(\mathbb{R},\cdot)$ as a semigroup, for non-zero real values, the semigroup inverse is the usual value, and the semigrouop inverse of 0 is 0.

Please take note that these are not normal inverses. For example if you had the equation
$ab=c$, it is not always possible to solve for $b$ using $b=a^{-1} c$, where $a^{-1}$ is the semigroup inverse.

In this case there is only one oddball element, so to make this distinction even clearer, consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ and define the operation $(a,b)\cdot(c,d) \rightarrow (ac,bd)$. This is an inverse semigroup.  However there are now non-zero elements $a,b,c$ where $ab=c$, yet $b \ne a^{-1} c$. For example, $a=(2,0),b=(2,3),c=(4,0)$. Therefore these "inverses" cannot be used like group inverses, even in this simple linear equation.

So these "inverses" do not give you a nice division operation in the way you may have hoped. Just like you still cannot divide 9 by 0 in your $(\mathbb{R},\cdot)$ inverse semigroup.

You note:

> ...this observation that the set R \ 0 makes product rules R5-R9 suspect.

No.
Nothing you said made the multiplication by 0 in the reals "suspect" just because the multiplicative group does not include the additive identity.

If you want to consider a structure including 0, it would be more appropriate to view the reals as a division algebra. This includes the interaction between addition and multiplication, in particular the distributive law. Now $(\mathbb{R},+)$ *is* a group involving all the real numbers, with the additive identity being 0. The distributive law tells us multiplication and addition interact such that the additive identity cannot be part of the multiplicative group. There is nothing mysterious about this, and it doesn't mean we are unable to discuss 0 with multiplication. The distributive law, and the fact that zero is the additive identity tells us that for any $a$:
$$ 0\cdot a = (0+0)\cdot a = 0\cdot a + 0\cdot a $$
Which is only possible if $0\cdot a$ is the additive identity and thus 0 times any number must be 0.

If you want to more meaningfully include how 0 (additive identity) interacts with the multiplicative group, you should focus on the structure that meaningfully combines them: the real numbers as a division algebra.

Comment: The _only_ way I mean an inverse exists is: x=x⋅y⋅x and y=y⋅x⋅y. a=(2,0), b=(2,3),c=(4,0) all have inverses. An element and its inverse is only about a relationship between those two.  The analysis of equation $ab=c$ is simply not relevant to the definition provided above. It is the presence of more than one identity that explains why one can find examples like the one provided that $b \ne a^{-1} c$. Having multiple identities has consequences. I don’t see how that breaks anything, it is merely a consequence of multiple identities.

Comment: So why is {$\mathbb{R}$, +} and {$\mathbb{R}$, x} different in terms of group theory? The former has an trivial subgroup that can be represented with exactly one element of $\mathbb{R}$, while the latter has a trivial subgroup that can be represented with two elements of $\mathbb{R}$. 

One could coin the phrase multi-identity disorder. That afflicts multiplication and not addition. The problem is apparent in expressions where both appear, as happens for the $ab=c$ example.

Comment: Because I have the insider knowledge of the context in which you ask this: you are trying to construct number systems where you can add, subtract, multiply, and divide ... it is clear that you want the inverse to be more than just a relationship between two numbers.  You want to be able to define a division operation. In a division algebra, multiplication by an element can be viewed as a map, and that map is invertible for all elements except the additive identity. THAT is what allows division. I feel you are getting hung up on the fact they reused the word "inverse" here.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, (R,x) is not a group. The actual multiplicative group has only a single trivial subgroup. To stretch your mind further, there are groups that can be represented as either additive or multiplicative. A cyclic group of prime-1 order can be viewed as a multiplicative group or as an additive group. For example ($\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ \ {0}, $\times$) which is isomorphic to ($\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, +).  In short, we can help describe properties and relations for you, but 'why' questions need to be broken down into something concrete.

Comment: Going back to multiplication by an element viewed as a map. The map of "multiply by 1" is trivial in that it is the identity map. "Multiply by zero" is trivial in that it maps all elements to zero. They are trivial in different ways. And the reason your 'every element gets its own identity' falls apart in division, is that you are no longer talking about an identity map. Without a division algebra, these multiplication maps are not one-to-one; they are "lossy"; you lose information.  No amount of looking for other structure or renaming things will fix this... the information is lost.

Comment: Information is "lost": 6x0=0 as well as 9x0=0, no telling the difference. Those are the rules of multiplying real numbers. I am only trying to build a structure where I can add and multiply, where both adding and multiplying have unique inverses such that $a = a a^{-1} a$ for every member. If all I need to say is I have inverse semigroups, I am fine with that and its consequences, such as the $ab=c$ example your provide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84664/discussion-between-ppenguin-and-sweetser).